# Angular Ionic slider blank after collection update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I have an instance of `ion-slides` on my page displaying some images:

```
<ion-slides class="to-top" pager>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of detailImages">
        <img src="{{ image }}" alt="">
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

The collection `detailImages` is loaded at the start on page load and is an collection of strings containing image URLs that point to my media provider. Here is where I load the detailImages (loaded on page load):

```
 loadDetailImages(ParentID: number) {
    this.detailService.getImagesCollection(ParentID).pipe(
        map(resp => {
            //Some mapping
        })
    ).subscribe(result => {
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            let urlString = "http://res.cloudinary.com/someuser/image/v123456/" + result[i].CloudinaryTag + ".jpg"
            this.detailImages.push(urlString)
        }

    });
}
```

So far this implementation works well. However, whenever I remove an item from `detailImages`, the whole pager goes blank (white) with nothing to scroll through.

Here is the code that removes the image from the collection:

```
deleteImage(imageURL: any) {
    this.detailService.deleteDetailImage({ imageURL: imageURL }).pipe(
        map(resp => {
            //Do some mapping working
        })
    ).subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
            this.detailImages.splice(this.slides.getActiveIndex(),1);
            this.slides.update();
            this.toastCtrl.create({ message: "Image Removed", showCloseButton: true,duration:3000 }).present();
        }
    });
}
```

I did try to update the slider:

```
 @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

 // and then after remove item call this
 this.slides.update();
```

But this had no effect. I am not sure if it is an Angular issue or Ionic Issue.

I'm using Angular 5.0.3 and Ionic-Angular 3.9.2

Comment: Can you share more of the code involved and also the value of detailImages

Comment: Will do @SergeyRudenko . Updated the post just no.

Comment: `detailImages` is same as `jobImages` ?

Comment: Oops sorry that was a mistake - I updated my post

Comment: where did you get the value of this `detailImages` ? to me after you delete an item on your slide call that function where did you load this `detailImages` object

Comment: I did try that, but the slides won't update, have to go back and return to the page (recreate/reload the view) for it to show the updated contents. Removing an  item from `detailImages` causes the slider to go blank. It would seem that the slider doesn't like it's collection altered.

Comment: It would be easier and quicker if you can create the stackblitz demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with adding `*ngIf="detailImages.length"` on `ion-slides` :

```
<ion-slides class="to-top" pager *ngIf="detailImages.length">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of detailImages">
        <img src="{{ image }}" alt="">
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>`
```

Answer (score 3):

To reload the UI manually, you can use Angular `ChangeDetectorRef`

In your `.ts` file

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

deleteImage(imageURL: any) {
    this.detailService.deleteDetailImage({ imageURL: imageURL }).pipe(
        map(resp => {
            //Do some mapping working
        })
    ).subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
            this.detailImages.splice(this.slides.getActiveIndex(),1);
            this.slides.update();
            this.toastCtrl.create({ message: "Image Removed", showCloseButton: true,duration:3000 }).present();
            // This will force all the components to reload
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will run change detection that could be okay if this service is outside the zone or the component is OnPush. Although if 'this.detailImages' have not changed, ngFor will not re-render. You have to make a copy before removing the element, something like: this.detailImages = [...this.detailImages]

Comment: It's changing when doing `this.detailImages.splice(this.slides.getActiveIndex(),1);`

Comment: the method 'splice' mutates it, but the array reference is still the same, so the ngFor doesn't know it has changed.

Comment: What do you mean ? When you remove an element from an array the ngfor instantly renders again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought ngFor array input was working as an Input binding. I upvote the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem - After some testing I noted that the issue only occured when I removed the last image in the slides. The error was being generated becuase the Ionic Slider Module remembers the last active index after it is refreshed and that cuases it to try and access an index that doesn't exist. To fix this issue, all I hadd to add was:

```
this.slides.slideTo(0);
```